# How to prevent uncheck (unselect) gridview item in windows Universal app

Tags: c#, gridview, uwp-xaml

In Windows Universal app, I have a pivot table which every tab content have gridview, gridview items are multi select mode,

What I want that if any one item once checked (selected), then it unable to unselect(uncheck)

```
<Grid DataContext="{Binding Path=Value}">
                            <GridView x:Name="categoryItemsGV" 
                                Margin="5,5,0,0"
                                SizeChanged="categoryItemsGV_SizeChanged"
                                IsItemClickEnabled="True"
                                ItemClick="categoryItemsGV_ItemClick"
                                SelectionMode="Single" 
                                ItemsSource="{Binding}">
                                <GridView.ItemContainerStyle>
                                    <Style TargetType="GridViewItem">
                                        <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
                                        <!--<Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>-->
                                    </Style>
                                </GridView.ItemContainerStyle>
                                <GridView.ItemTemplate>
                                    <DataTemplate>
                                        <Grid Width="195" Height="43" Margin="3">
                                            <StackPanel Width="193" Height="40"  Background="Gray" Opacity="0.5" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" />
                                            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Width="193" Height="40" Padding="7,7,0,0" Background="#FDFCC2"  HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top">
                                                <TextBlock  Text="{Binding ProductOptionLineName}" FontSize="18" MaxLines="1" TextTrimming="CharacterEllipsis"   Visibility="{Binding Converter={StaticResource langToVisibilityConverter}, ConverterParameter='CH', Mode=OneWay}">
                                                </TextBlock>
                                                <TextBlock  Text="{Binding ProductOptionLineNameEn}" FontSize="18" MaxLines="1" TextTrimming="CharacterEllipsis"  Visibility="{Binding Converter={StaticResource langToVisibilityConverter}, ConverterParameter='EN', Mode=OneWay}"/>
                                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding ExtraPriceString}" FontSize="18" Margin="2,0,0,0"></TextBlock>
                                            </StackPanel>
                                        </Grid>
                                    </DataTemplate>
                                </GridView.ItemTemplate>
                            </GridView>
                        </Grid>


  private async void categoryItemsGV_ItemClick(object sender, ItemClickEventArgs e)
        {

                var item = e.ClickedItem as ProductOptionLineModel;
       }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If we want to keep item selected as it was already selected, use below approach.

```
 private async void categoryItemsGV_ItemClick(object sender, ItemClickEventArgs e)
        {

                var item = e.ClickedItem as ProductOptionLineModel;
                        GridView gv = sender as GridView;
                        gv.SelectedItems.Remove(item);
       }
```

and if we want to keep item deselect on click (prevent deselected) for validation purpose. used below approach.

```
private async void categoryItemsGV_ItemClick(object sender, ItemClickEventArgs e)
        {

                var item = e.ClickedItem as ProductOptionLineModel;
                            await   _viewModel.DialogService("FirstRequireMinOption", "", true);
                            GridView gv = sender as GridView;
                            gv.SelectedItems.Add(item);
       }
```

Answer (score 1):

We can use the [`SelectRange(ItemIndexRange)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.ListViewBase#Windows_UI_Xaml_Controls_ListViewBase_SelectRange_Windows_UI_Xaml_Data_ItemIndexRange_) method to selects a block of items described by the ItemIndexRange.

> When you call SelectRange(ItemIndexRange), all items in the specified range are selected, regardless of their original selection state. You can select all items in a collection by using an ItemIndexRange with a FirstIndex value of 0 and a Length value equal to the number of items in the collection.

For more info, see [Remarks of the SelectRange(ItemIndexRange)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.ListViewBase#Windows_UI_Xaml_Controls_ListViewBase_SelectRange_Windows_UI_Xaml_Data_ItemIndexRange_).

We can use the `ItemClick` to get which item is be clicked. Then we can add the `SelectionChanged` event and set the number of the clicked item to the `SelectRange` method.

For example:

```
private int number;

private void categoryItemsGV_ItemClick(object sender, ItemClickEventArgs e)
{
    var item = e.ClickedItem as ProductOptionLineModel;
    number = ProductOptionLineModels.IndexOf(item);
}

private void categoryItemsGV_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    categoryItemsGV.SelectRange(new ItemIndexRange(number, 1));
}
```